# In R, how can I plot the location of item with their source on europe map using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I want to plot the location("longitude" and "latitude") of each item with their "source" (e.g. English, French, Korean or Japanese) like Below picture.

[image]

To do this, I prepare a 'csv' file including "longitude", "latitude" and "source" like below, which is a sample of population.

```
latitude    longitude   source
51.318488   -1.0605415  English
51.4603395  -0.115406   Korean
47.9818605  0.195548    English
40.226213   28.954341   English
53.717188   27.978099   English
45.800371   9.0838175   French
41.292651   12.573501   French
41.8984165  12.5451455  Japanese
53.651504   -2.6340755  English
48.382929   31.181446   Korean
40.176071   29.121293   English
51.6471965  -0.7084465  English
40.54108    -3.63148    English
40.6280185  -8.6396565  French
51.5424365  -0.159403   French
36.89007    30.680889   Japanese
48.8588335  2.347003    English
52.238854   -0.882951   Korean
37.383198   -5.923545   English
45.080766   11.5820475  English
41.392657   2.1412275   English
41.0213205  29.0052225  French
53.0184905  -1.356315   French
```

I tried this here but It did not work. And from map_data, I could get only "world", "france" and "states".

```
df <- read.csv("data", header =T, sep = ',')
world_map <- map_data("world")
ggplot(world_map, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = group)) + geom_polygon(fill="lightgray", colour = "white") geom_polygon(aes( group = group, fill = region)) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = source), size = 1, alpha = 1/5, color = "darkblue")

theme(axis.line = element_blank(), 
  axis.text = element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
  axis.title = element_blank(), 
  panel.background = element_blank(), 
  panel.border = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
  plot.background = element_blank())
```

How can I do make the above first picture?

Comment: A couple things: you're missing a `+` in your code. We also don't need 9 lines of theme-setting code for a question that isn't about the theme, especially since you're missing the `+` there as well that would attach that to the actual plot. As for countries, that package doesn't have shapefiles for every country—the ones included are just common references. You'll have to find your own shapefiles that you want; the Natural Earth project is a great resource for this. Please be more specific about what doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample of the data you provided, I can get something onto the map. I do not have a registered google api so I manually restricted the map based on the data frame you have:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

world_map <- map_data("world")
# so call map of europe
# will change according to what you have in df
world_map = subset(world_map,long < max(df$longitude )+5 & long > min(df$longitude)-5)
world_map = subset(world_map,lat < max(df$latitude)+5 & lat > min(df$latitude)-5)
# to get city names
LAB = world_map %>% 
group_by(region) %>% 
select(region,long,lat) %>% 
summarise_all(mean)

#plot
ggplot(world_map, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
geom_polygon(aes( group = group, fill = region),show.legend=FALSE,alpha=1/5) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = source), 
size = 1) + 
geom_text(data=LAB,aes(label=region),size=2)+
scale_fill_grey() +theme_map()
```

Not the best, but maybe if you play around with colours etc can get better

[image]